# Shell script: For loop unexpected output

Tags: shell

I have a requirement where I have to read the names of the sub directories and copy the names to a file. Following is the code that I have written.

```
 for file in $HOME/AutoQA/screenshots/*
 do
 if [ -d "$file" ];
     then
        echo "$file" >> $HOME/AutoQA/FailedTestCases.txt
  fi
done
```

Now the above code works almost perfectly but the output that I get is something like

```
/home/AutoQA/screenshots/1
/home/AutoQA/screenshots/2
......
```

But I expect it to be as follows

```
1
2
....
```

So I need only the names of the sub directories. Here before running the for loop, I dont want to do

```
cd /home/AutoQA/screenshots/
```

How can I manage that? Can anyone help?

Comment: If you add a trailing `/` to your glob, it will expand to directory  names only, removing the need for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
echo "$file" >> $HOME/AutoQA/FailedTestCases.txt
```

with

```
basename "$file" >> $HOME/AutoQA/FailedTestCases.txt
```